# Python Regex Findall script tags

Tags: python, regex, string

Hello I want to have a list of all the javascript inside, this is my code:

```
m= re.findall(r"(?:.*>)(.*)(?:<)", "<scrip>hola</scRIHft> <script=>nano</script>")


if m:
    print m
```

And I want to have a list with hola and nano, but I only print nano.

Could anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

```
In [2]: re.findall(r"(?<=>)[^<]*(?=</)", "<scrip>hola</scRIHft> <script=>nano</script>")                                                                                   
Out[2]: ['hola', 'nano']
```

btw, your tags are not well-formed, it doesn't matter for the regex/extraction, but you may want to check it.